# Powershell script to scan a target directory

Tags: powershell

I am getting an error when trying to scan a target directory within Powershell.

The code I am using is;

```
    $path = read-host 'Enter the target drive letter'

    $objects = get-childitem $path -force -recurse
```

Essentially what I want to do is get this general search working (scanning a user-specified location) so that I can then refine it to search for specific items such as files by filetype, size etc. When this runs, however, I get an error when the path contains a space, such as the 'documents and settings' or 'program files' folders in the drive.

Is there any way I can do this without getting this error? I am quite new to powershell, and I couldn't see this answered anywhere else, but I apologise if this has already been covered elsewhere.

### Update:

It's running on Powershell v2.0. Thinking about it, the reason I thought it was space-related is because these are the only items which seem to error, but the message itself says;

```
    Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied. At
    C:\users\robert\desktop\v1.ps1:5 char:25 + $objects = get-childitem <<<<  $path
    - force -recurse + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (C:\Documents and
    Settings:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException +
    FullyQualifiedErrorId :
    DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Sorry if this was misleading, I thought as I was running this as an administrator with unrestricted execution policy the permissions shouldn't be a problem, but if this is what's actually causing it is there a way to override this so it will scan everything on the target drive?

Comment: I don't understand when and where you have the error, could you add the error in your question?

Comment: is this powershell 1 or 2 as this works just fine in 3

Comment: Please post the error. Be aware that `Get-ChildItem` returns non-terminating errors(it will continue to search) if you scan e.g. `c:\` because some files in the "windows" are protected.

Comment: Its a permission issue for documents and settings folder.

Comment: Is there anyway to override these permissions? I would need the script to be able to run on various drives and the full drive would need to be scanned, not just the folders which aren't protected. I would have thought that as I'm currently writing / testing the script on my own laptop and running it as an administrator that it should have access to these folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use: (see additional double quotes)

```
$objects = get-childitem "$path" -force -recurse
```

Comment: I've no error without double quote why you suggest this? no error on powershell v2.0 and v3.0.. maybe in v1.0? Read-host returns always a string also with spaces inside..

Answer (score 0):

Vista or Windows 7? Maybe no problem, if it's just stumbling on the "Documents and Settings" [junction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the root. The junction links to c:\users and maybe gci doesn't follow the link, to prevent a circular or incomplete search. Here's another way to stumble on this:

at vanilla cmd:

```
cd 'C:\documents and settings'
explorer .
```

On Win7 I get a popup error message:

```
Location is not available
C:\documents and settings is not accessible
Access is denied
```

No error with `cd 'C:\documents and settings'` and the shell returns a prompt inside that folder (as opposed to the link target, c:\users); and running the single command `explorer 'C:\documents and settings'` launches the My Documents folder without error ...but i digress.

We wouldn't want our recursive searches running in endless [loops](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/776397/robocopy-exe-error-1921-recursive-junctions-reparse-points) or skipping folders between 'Documents and Settings' and Users. Maybe get-childItem should handle this in some better way, dunno.

Meanwhile, you could exclude junction points this way. I haven't tested large recursive searches this way, but they might run longer.

```
gci "c:\" -force | where {($_.attributes.toString() -like "*ReparsePoint*") -eq $false}
```

Results do not include 'Documents and Settings' unless we swap `$true` for `$false`.